# Error installing grails with SDK - Curl issue

Tags: grails, curl, terminal, zip, sdkman

I am having trouble installing Grails via SDK.I installed SDK via the instruction on https://grails.org/download.html#sdkman and sdk installed correctly

```
$ sdk version
SDKMAN 5.1.4+78`
```

But when I executed

```
$ sdk install grails
```

I am getting output in the terminal

```
$ sdk install grails

Downloading: grails 3.2.0.RC2

In progress...

######################################################################## 100.0%
curl: (56) SSLRead() return error -36
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /Users/hwmehwme/.sdkman/archives/grails-3.2.0.RC2.zip or
        /Users/hwmehwme/.sdkman/archives/grails-3.2.0.RC2.zip.zip, and cannot find /Users/hwmehwme/.sdkman/archives/grails-3.2.0.RC2.zip.ZIP, period.

Stop! The archive was corrupt and has been removed! Please try installing again.
```

I do restarting the terminal and installed again but same issue again.

What am I missing in installation? is there other dependency is needed ? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It will be `SSL error `. you need to reinstall `curl with ssl` depend on OS after removed `curl`.

Comment: Thanks ubatin :) .I solved it by another reference [http://macappstore.org/grails/](http://macappstore.org/grails/) .It worked for me. Thanks for your time.

Comment: the reference to macappstore is down, could you write here how you solved the issue? I cannot make SDK to instal grails eighter